# The average value of irreducible character of a non-trivial finite group

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

> Let $G$ be a non-trivial  finite group. Let $\chi$ be an irreducible character of the group $G$. Find $$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} {\chi( g)}$$

I try. But I think that I am wrong. $$G=C_{i_1}\oplus C_{i_2}\oplus\ldots C_{i_k},$$
 as $C_{i}$ is a cyclic group
If $\chi$ is 1-dimensional character then $\sum_{g \in C_{m}} {\chi( g)}=0.$ Thus $$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} {\chi( g)}= \frac{k}{|G|}.$$
Am I on the right path?

There are not answer or hints in our book

Comment: You're not on the right path. I suggest 1) try some examples using whatever character tables you can find 2) think about the definition of the inner product of characters $\langle \chi, \phi\rangle$

Comment: "Thus [formula]." Where are you getting the formula? Also, whether or not we know $G$ is abelian (the gray block doesn't say even though you write a factor decomposition of $G$) is important, since it determines how tough the proof may be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an extension of the comment by mt_:

Consider the definition of the inner product on the characters $\langle \chi,\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)\overline{\psi(g)}$.

Can you get the sum you are looking as an inner product between suitable characters?

Comment: Using  character tables I assume that  $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} {\chi( g)}=0$ as affording irreducible representation is non-trivial and $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} {\chi( g)}=1$ as  affording irreducible representation  is trivial.  I want get the sum  looking as an inner product.  Сonsider representation representation $ \alpha=\rho \otimes \bar{\sigma}$. we have $$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} {\chi( g)}= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi_{\rho}(g)\overline{\chi_{\bar{\sigma}}(g)}=0, \text{as  $\rho \otimes \bar{\sigma}$ is n non-trivial}.$$  Does this make sense?

Comment: I don't quite follow what you mean. The sum you are looking at is simply the inner product of $\chi$ with the trivial character.

Comment: Oh, Yes! I at last understood!

Answer (score 0):

Apply the orthogonality relations.

Alternatively, consider an irreducible representation $\mathscr{X}$ affording $\chi$. Let $A = \sum_{g \in G} \mathscr{X}(g)$. Prove that either $A = 0$ or $\mathscr{X}$ is the trivial representation.

Comment: Using character tables I assume that  $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} {\chi( g)}=0$ as affording irreducible representation is non-trivial and $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} {\chi( g)}=1$ as  affording irreducible representation  is trivial.  I want get the sum  looking as an inner product.  Сonsider representation representation $ A=\rho \otimes \bar{\sigma}$. we have $$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} {\chi( g)}= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi_{\rho}(g)\overline{\chi_{\bar{\sigma}}(g)}=0, \text{as  $\rho \otimes \bar{\sigma}$ is n non-trivial}.$$  Does this make sense?